# Телеграмм Бот не реагирует на фотографию

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота на айограм. Не очень знаком с этой системой, поэтому пользуюсь прошлогодними ресурсами. Проблема в том, что нигде не могу найти ответа на свою проблему, а заключается она вот в чем.

Пишу админку для бота (бот нацелен на бизнес проект), соответственно он должен показывать некоторый товар пользователю, какой администратор соизволит внести в список. Но когда вносишь новый товар, на моменте отправки фотографии бот попросту не реагирует (то есть он просто молчит).

Вот так завел переменную под фотку:

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    photo_id = State()
    ...
```

Вот сама часть кода, отвечающая за фото:

```
#Начало диалога загрузки нового пункта меню
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        await FSMAdmin.photo_id.set()
        await message.reply('Загрузите фото')

#Ловим первый ответ и пишем в словарь
async def load_photo(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo_id'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Введите название')

#Ловим второй ответ
async def load_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply("Введите описание товара (подробно)")
```

Так как код раскидан по разным папкам, то приходиться вызывать его через регистратор команды, вот он:

```
...
dp.register_message_handler(load_photo, commands = ['photo'], state = FSMAdmin.photo_id)
...
```

Пытался искать проблему и в создании бота, но все безуспешно. Вот конечный код, отвечающий за бота:

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

storage = MemoryStorage()

bot = Bot(token = 'засекречено')
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage = storage)
```

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что делаю не так, потому что уже неделю не могу найти нужного для себя ответа? Ошибку не выдает, бот в онлайн выходит. Если понадобится еще какая часть кода, могу прислать. Пишу в Саблайм, в основном обращаюсь к этому уроку [(Видеоурок, по которому писал код)](https://youtu.be/nF1p1JjuR3U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, проблема в том, что Вы указали команду /photo вместо content_types=['photo'] в аргументе регистратора.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. Видимо уже настолько приелся этот код, что не увидел этого момента.

Если у кого тоже такая ошибка, но не понял, о чем речь, то в моменте регистрации кода:

`dp.register_message_handler(load_photo, commands = ['photo'], state = FSMAdmin.photo_id)`

нужно `commands=['photo']`, заменить на `content_types=['photo']`